# No sound on Asus Zenbook UX430 with Ubuntu desktop 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus, headphones

Recently I installed Ubuntu desktop 18.04.1 on my laptop along with Microsoft Windows 10. Everything works perfectly, until two or three times using Ubuntu, the sound completely went away. Meaning that Ubuntu is completely mute in every way. No sound in headphone, speakers, HDMI, etc. I checked and the system completely recognizes the audio card and also knows all the audio devices. But I do not understand the problem. I tried some of the online terminal methods. None of them worked.

I also reinstalled Ubuntu three times but every time the same thing happens.

The only things that I've done are installing Google Chrome, Anaconda 3 and usual applications from Ubuntu store not related to sound.

How can I have the sound back on the system?

(System: Asus Zenbook UX430)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved automatically after a while. Then it happened again now. There was no answer to my question, but I figured out by my self.
Just shutdown!!!
I was doing restart and trying different things to fix. But the solution simply is to shutdown the computer and turn it on again.

Comment: Could you provide any clarification of this answer? Do you mean that fully shutting down the machine is necessary to get the sound back every time this happens, or that doing so once will be sufficient to make the problem go away permanently? Or was something else involved here, like a routine system update?

Comment: It happened three times. I have native windows 10. I installed 18.04 and it had this problem. I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 after a while and happened again. And two days ago. I reinstalled alsamixer and other drivers but it didn't help.I was restarting the system all the time. But I realized if you shut the system completely down and turn it on again, you will have the sound back.
This is just a hypotheses but I think when you are on windows some stuff goes to registry and to change the OS you need to shut down and turn on again. Because apparently with restart they do not change and remain.

Comment: Here just to say I have had the same problem and solved it same way. Problem seems to occur on Windows + Ubuntu setups. Windows not fully shot down seems can to cause sound problems to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Asus Zenbook UX430UA, all you have to do, every time sound doesnt work put your laptop on **Sleep Mode** and the sound will work!

But, I still have problem headphones doesnt work!

Comment: You just need to shot down on windows and boot up directly on ubuntu.

Comment: I did it but still same problem, i deleted windows and i installed only ubuntu, still same problem!

Comment: Guys, i found the solution!!!!, edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (I think on some computers, it may be just alsa.conf) and insert this as the last line: options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (I think on some computers, it may be just alsa.conf) and insert this as the last line: options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode